# Hadoop installation on Ubuntu, Hadoop file VS Hortonworks or Cloudera

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform

I'm trying to install Hadoop on my machine. Currently I have Windows and Ubuntu OS. I've been searching for possible ways of installing Hadoop and I came across Hortonworks website. From their website, they provide sandbox for the Virtual machine, don't know if there is option installing directly on the OS. The question would it be different installing from http://hadoop.apache.org/? or installing something like Hortonworks or Cloudera? I have read that working with hadoop file is much better for understanding Hadoop, but would it be suitable for someone who want only create an app with it? I prefer to work with OS not the VM.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes,there is a option of installing Hadoop. You will have to setup your own Hadoop Cluster.
Please see the following links:

[Hadoop for Linux](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html)

[Hadoop for Windows](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hadoop2OnWindows)

Now,coming to Cloudera,HortonWorks,MapR.

These provide machines in which they have setup hadoop cluster on OS i.e Linux.
Download these machines from their site and run on VM. You don't need to do any installation.

So,Yes both are different processes.

Comment: Thanks but does Cloudera, HortonWorks and MapR work with VM only?

Comment: Yes,you will have to run a machine provided by them that is built on some other OS ,so you need VM for doing so.

Comment: I see! Thank you very much